# Google Test To Doxygen Page

Tags: xml, xslt, markdown, doxygen, googletest

I have a question about Google Tests and Doxygen:
It is possible to export the result in the form of an XML, is it possible to transpose the result so that it is readable by Doxygen. Adding the xml just makes it possible to open it.
Is there a way to display it properly? Or another more readable output format?
In the absolute, I used, at one time, mocha and find a visual as complete would be cool.

Edit : sorry the previous message was not clear and complete. Some more détails. for example Google test give me this xml document.
[Gist GoogleTestReport.xml](https://gist.github.com/tmonseigne/4ec72f54afef200e6d4991eda64ea251)
I have Doxygen with a Doxyfile to create my Documentation. [Gist Doxyfile](https://gist.github.com/tmonseigne/37f5907cb18de3382aa2955f29da28e7)

I added the xml in input of doxygen masi it's ugly and he just puts me a link to the xml he opens next.
Is there a way to interpret the xml to make a clean html page with Doxygen?
or
Is there another type of google test output that Doxygen can interpret (be it a markdown page or whatever)?

Comment: Can you give some more details of what you want and also a small example so in general: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Then, present us a clear description of what are you trying to do, what you got wrong and what you expected to get, along with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1) I don't see the Doxyfile. 2) are there any other files involved where you reference the xml file?

Comment: When I understand it correctly you want to display the `xml` file in a more readable form. Doxygen does not understand `xml` as such and displays it in the source code browser as is (what I even didn't expect, I would think it would skip it). To have the xml in a more readable format you will need to make something like a `xslt` and convert it or try to export it in markdown format (can be understood by doxygen) or e.g. in docbook format and process it from there on. Another possibility is to write a filter for doxygen and give the results in a form so that doxygen does understand it.

Comment: 1) Sorry bad link for the Doxyfile, it's fixed

2) Yes you understand. For the markdown it's a part of my question and simplest way I think but I don't see where are the output option of google test I found only some topics with xml output.  

3) I did not know the xslt and Doxygen filter It's maybe the solution  

[xml display on Doxygen](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/45/3/1541594245-googletest-xml-on-doxygen.jpg)

Comment: I don't get the " It's maybe the solution xml display on Doxygen", this is just showing the `xml` as is in the doxygen source code browser.

Comment: Yes, it was the previous state. I found a basic xslt and a way to convert my xml to readable html, now I need to find a version for markdown instead of HTML. Otherwise I will have the same problem by adding the html to the sources of doxygen. It will not display the page properly.
The markdown files are interpreted correctly and placed in related page

Comment: thank you for taking time for me. ^^

Comment: A limited number of HTML commands are understood by doxygen, so a small filter might be enough to show the result. Please share the resulting HTML of the xml you showed before.

Comment: The file on output [Gist html](https://gist.github.com/tmonseigne/31810f5afac587b141253dc3c28b9f37)

Comment: Found the file/ I'm looking into the possibilities / necessities for a filter and other possibilities.

Comment: Meanwhile, i am also looking for a way to edit a good xsl that i found to save the xml in markdown. If we can propose two solutions for those who would ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to make a HTML link on a page and copy the HTML file like:

- `<a href="GoogleTestReport.html">The report</a>`
- set the `EXTRA_HTML_FILES = GoogleTestReport.html`

Another possibility would be:

- create a filter (note order is important):

  - take only part between (but excluding) `<body>` and `</body>`
  - replacing all `\` by `\\` (especially in paths)
  - replace the multiple `=` by `\=`, but as this currently not supported by doxygen replace the multiple `=` by `\-`. A proposed patch has been submitted already: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/6608
  - add the filter to the configuration setting `FILTER_PATTERNS`
  - add an extension mapping `EXTENSION_MAPPING = html=md`
- create a style sheet:

  - take (possibly only necessary once)the part in a report file between (but excluding) `<style>` and `</style>`
  - remove the lines in the body tag of the stylesheet:

    - `width: 80%;`
    - `margin: 40px auto;`
  - add the created stylesheet to the configuration setting `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`

A further possibility is to save the report in markdown format and give this file to doxygen (maybe including a filter as not all markdown is handled by doxygen).

Answer (score 0):

A new [filter for Doxygen](https://github.com/msillano/filters_dox) 1.8.15 allows processing of (X)HTML, XML, XSL(T) files.

**Rules for (X)HTML, XML:**

```
<po:purchaseOrder ....>
<!-- /**
     *  this block is extract and processed by Doxygen 
     */ -->
   <skipTo> .....
   ......
```

In detailed documentation you can have a  sintax high-lighted colored collassable tree of full HML, (X)HTML. 
javascript (if any) is processed as usual by Doxygen

**Rules for XSL(T):**

Every "xsl:template" becomes a pseudo-function and can have a comment block.
In detailed documentation you can have a sintax high-lighted colored collassable tree of the template node.

In hope that can help.

Best regards.

m.s.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't enough time to see this now but I keep your link in my check list.